# Auto Refresh of a label text in ASP Masterpage without loading of entire page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I have a label control in ASP Master Page whose text will be loaded on Page_Load of Master page.

Master page :

```
<asp:label id="Label1"> </asp:label>
```

Master.cs file:

```
Protected void Page_load()
{
   Label1.text = " Data Refreshed at :" + getUpdatedTimestamp();
}
```

This Label represents the updated timestamp when the data is refreshed in database. We are hitting DB by function getUpdatedTimestamp();

So, if the use navigate to other page, then as the master page gets loaded again we will be able to get the updated timestamp as we hit the database in page_load event of master page.

**My question here would be : Is there any way to hit the DB and get the updated timestamp even if the user stays on the same page with out navigating to other page.**

Note: I have tried the update panel in master page and set triggers to hit DB but for that i need to add a script manager to master page. I already had the script manager for all the content pages and is not able to add the script manager to master page. So, this option is ruled out.

Could anybody please suggest me the suitable approach to get this done.!!!

I also tried the javascript **function setinterval()** to get this done but got stuck with calling server side function in javascript function.

Comment: show the code you tried with javascript and ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using script manager to update only a small label may lead to overhead in data transfered from server.

I suggest using client-side javascript which will call server-side WebMethod at interval.

Create a WebMethod on your ASPX.CS page:

```
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static string GetCurrentTime()
    {
        return DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }
```

In client-side code fetch the server WebMethod using jQuery AJAX call, and show the server response in a label:

```
<html>
    <head runat="server">
        <enter code here!-- jQuery required -->
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function ShowCurrentTime() {
                // Ajax call to YOUR_PAGE.aspx/GetCurrentTime
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Default.aspx/GetCurrentTime", // Change Default.aspx to your ASPX page name, and GetCurrentTime to your server-side WebMethod name
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: OnSuccess // OnSuccess method is called when AJAX request receives the data from the server
                });
            }

            function OnSuccess(response) {
                // The response will contain JSON object like {"d":"29.6.2014 13:21:47"},
                // so the actual data is response.d
                $("#lblCurrentTime").text(response.d); // Fill our SPAN label with the data. 
            }

            $(function () {
                // Call every 1000 miliseconds
                window.setInterval(ShowCurrentTime, 1000);
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <!-- LABEL TO SHOW CURRENT TIME -->
            <span id="lblCurrentTime"></span>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

That's it. This way there will be as little data transfer from the server as possible. Calling server-side WebMethod will not produce as big performance hit on the server as standard postbacks do, because WebMethod avoids standard page lifecycle events.

More info:

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Call-ASPNet-Page-Method-using-jQuery-AJAX-Example.aspx

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/byxd99hx(v=vs.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/byxd99hx%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Hi . . Thanks a lot for ur approach and I have done the same. But my question here would be " Can we call the method in the master page? "....... I mean, url: "EMARMaster.Master/GetUpdatedTimestamp", can it be like this instead of aspx?   Because when i inserted a breakpoint in the master.cs file at the function, it is not hitting for every time interval. But if if replace the whole method with simple Alert("Hi") for every setinterval 10 sec, it works. Hope u got it what i need exactly..!!!!! Thanks a ton in advance.

Comment: AFAIK you can use WebMethod in master pages. If you need to call a specific web method from multiple web pages, the best approach is to create ASMX (web service) file instead of ASPX (eg. MasterWebService.asmx), and copy into it the same [WebMethod] function as I had explained for ASPX. Then in javascript call ajax using url: "MasterWebService.asmx/GetUpdatedTimestamp". For more info please read the first 3 chapters in http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-ajax/understanding-asp-net-ajax-web-services. ASMX files provide better performance for hosting web services, comparing to ASPX.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to put your label inside a UpdatePanel so you can update the label without reloading the whole page.
If you have done that you need to set up a trigger to execute an action (in your case updating the time stamp)

Comment: Hi. . thanks a lot for ur approach. . But i can't add the script manager in the master page(due to update panel) as all of my child pages have script manager in it.!!!